# Why proc does not need a % symbol when written inside a SAS macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a basic question about SAS macro. Inside sas macro, when you write a let statement or a put statement or an if statement, you always prefix it with %.

But when you write a 'proc' inside a macro, why don't we need to write %proc?
Or for example %data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%` denotes macro syntax - macro functions, macro statements, or macro commands.  Basically, things that would be covered by the [SAS Macro Language Reference](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/62978/PDF/default/mcrolref.pdf).

When you have a proc in a macro, what you're asking the macro to do is to type that proc onto the stack as if you'd typed it.  You don't need a `%` because the proc is the text you're asking be typed, not a command to the macro language interpreter itself.

SAS Macro language and SAS Base are two essentially separate languages - the latter is the core of SAS, the former is a helper that can make it easier to do certain repetitive things.  They're only loosely integrated.

The `%let` or `%put` are macro statements: they are not the same thing as the `put` you can use in the data step.  They share the name and basic idea of functionality, but nothing else any more than `printf` in [c](/questions/tagged/c) and `printf` in [r](/questions/tagged/r) share in common.

Answer (score 9):

Because the data step language and macro language are two different programming environments. When SAS tokenizes your statements, it looks for specific keywords. One of those keywords is the `%` trigger. Before anything is run, the word scanner separates out macro statements from SAS statements and passes them to the appropriate processor. Macro statements are always compiled and resolved before SAS statements.

When you are working with macros, you're storing text strings in either some macro variable or macro program. Anything inside of the macro variable or program is raw text as far as SAS is concerned.

Consider the following two macros:

Macro 1:

```
%macro foo1;
    data bar1;
       var1 = 'a';
       var2 = 'b';
       var3 = 'c';
       var4 = 'd';

       keep var1-var3;
    run;
%mend;
```

Macro 2:

```
%macro foo2;
       keep
       %do i = 1 %to 3;
           var&i
       %end;
%mend;

data bar2;
   var1 = 'a';
   var2 = 'b';
   var3 = 'c';
   var4 = 'd';

   %foo2;
run;
```

When you compile Macro 1, nothing happens until you call it. This is because you have stored all of that text inside of a macro program. When you call the macro statement:

```
%foo1;
```

SAS passes the phrase `foo1` to the macro processor, the program is run, and the resolved text is spat back into the word scanner, which then processes the individual tokens one by one.  As far as SAS is concerned, it sees exactly the datastep contained inside:

```
data bar1;
   var1 = 'a';
   var2 = 'b';
   var3 = 'c';
   var4 = 'd';

   keep var1-var3;
run;
```

When we run Macro 2, we'll get the exact same output, but it's being performed differently.

When we compile the macro `foo2`, we also store some information about an internal macro loop. This particular loop simply creates the text "var1 var2 var3" sequentially. Notice that there's a piece of text right before the loop: "keep." This is completely valid since it's just a piece of text.

We execute the macro inside of the data step. When we start the compilation process of the data step, the word scanner finds the macro trigger `%` and passes that information along to the macro processor.  When it finds that `foo2` is a valid compiled macro, the macro processor runs the macro program, and the resulting text is sent over to the word scanner:

```
keep
var1
var2
var3
```

We end invocation of the macro with a semicolon on purpose. This tells the word scanner that we are at the end of a statement, which eventually gets sent over to the compiler.

Once the macro is complete, the word scanner keeps chugging along, passing statements to the input stack until it hits the `run` boundary, or another `proc` step.

We could invoke `foo2` outside of a data step, but SAS will error out saying that they're not valid statements. It's equivalent to typing `keep var1 var2 var3;` on a line and trying to run it. That specific piece of text is only useful inside of a data step, though SAS will happily attempt to run it wherever you want.

SAS doesn't see macros. It only understands data step and proc language. Only the macro processor can see and make use of macro triggers. The word scanner prevents the compiler from seeing any of the macro triggers. Think of the word scanner like a special filter: it hands out text only to the places that can read it.

There are a few exceptions where some functions in the data step can bridge the gap between SAS and macros, but it doesn't really have anything to do with this.

Answer (score 2):

For the same reason that I don't have to type `<>` around the words in my webpage when I am editing the HTML.  The words in my webpage are not HTML commands the same way that SAS code statements are not commands to the SAS macro processor.